# Throwing error when trying to create a new instance of an webserver object in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, qt, oop

In my class I am trying to create a new instance of my webserver object:

**.h**

```
class Stub : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Stub(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~Stub();    

private:
    WebSocketServer *m_webSocketServer;
```

**.cpp**

```
Stub::Stub(QObject *parent)
    : QObject(parent)
{
    //Start Websocket-Server
    m_webSocketServer = new WebSocketServer(8000, true,this);   
}
```

My server constructor looks like:

```
explicit WebSocketServer(quint16 port, bool v = true, QObject *parent = Q_NULLPTR);
```

but it throws errors like this:

> Error 7   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual __thiscall
>   WebSocketServer::~WebSocketServer(void)"
>   (__imp_??1WebSocketServer@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function "public:
>   virtual void * __thiscall WebSocketServer::`scalar deleting
>   destructor'(unsigned int)" (??
>
> Error 10  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual
>   void * __thiscall WebSocketServer::qt_metacast(char const *)"
>   (?qt_metacast@WebSocketServer@@UAEPAXPBD@Z)
>
> Error 8   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual
>   struct QMetaObject const * __thiscall
>   WebSocketServer::metaObject(void)const "
>   (?metaObject@WebSocketServer@@UBEPBUQMetaObject@@XZ)
>
> Error 9   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual int
>   __thiscall WebSocketServer::qt_metacall(enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)"
>   (?qt_metacall@WebSocketServer@@UAEHW4Call@QMetaObject@@HPAPAX@Z)

my webserver is working, just when creating instance of that it crashes.
I tried adding libraries, included .h files, all names match

Comment: It does not crash. It gets linker errors. Seems like you declared the destructor but did not implement it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: That's a very peculiar definition of "working". I don't think my manager would buy it.

Comment: @molbdnilo just wanted to tell you, I think its not important to show code of that. its actualy a library that I imported

Comment: @DušanTichý I suspect that you forgot to link with that library.

Comment: @molbdnilo I included header files and lib files for linker, probably not the problem, when I comment that creating of new instance, everything works

Comment: @Hayt destructor is implemented.

Comment: where is you class `WebSocketServer`implemented? unresolved external symbols mean you have declared something which is not defined.

Comment: @Hayt sorry if I have stupid questions, what u mean where? I have all the file at disk... i just include headers and added lib file in project properties.
thanks for trying to help.

Comment: Is `WebSocketServer` your class? Like do you have a cpp file for it? And does the cpp file gets compiled?

Comment: I have .cpp, I dont know if its compiled, when i try to compile just header file with its declaration, it is compiled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it:

What I had to do:

1. Checked again if I added libraries and I noticed I put it to wrong place

**Project -> Properties -> Configuration Properties -> Linker -> General -> Additional dependencies**

but It was supposed to be inside this:

**Project -> Properties -> Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Input-> Additional dependencies**

2. Even when I added it correctly, I got error with missing .dll file, so what I've done is I put missing .dll copy into output directory (**Project -> Properties -> Configuration Properties -> General-> Output Directory**)

Now it works as I intened.

Thanks all for effort.